# Magento 1.9.2.4 : Owl carousel not working

Tags: magento-1.9, jquery, slider, conflict

I want to add an owl carousel to my homepage (as a banner slider and product slider) I have linked every file everything is working fine except owl carousel even I have tried to use a slick slider instead of it but its also not working
here is my linked files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl(); ?>css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl(); ?>css/owl.carousel.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl(); ?>css/owl.theme.default.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T8Gy5hrqNKT+hzMclPo118YTQO6cYprQmhrYwIiQ/3axmI1hQomh7Ud2hPOy8SP1" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl(); ?>js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl(); ?>js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

and javascript code for owl carousel:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#slider').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:0,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:1
        },
        1000:{
            items:1
        }
    }
})
})
```

I have even tried jQuery.noConflict() but it's not working tried commenting other jquery code but still not working.

Comment: Can i get your screenshot of errors in console

Comment: And enqueue your `css` and `js` files using local.xml ,,this is proper way

Comment: its showing type error owl.carousel is not a function error

Comment: its not even working on local

Comment: i've just created a new file linked only css and js file and owl carousel code its still not working

Answer (score 1):

> Proper way to work with `owl-Carousel`

To your `Enqueue` your css and js files

### app\design\frontend\vendor\theme\layout - local.xml

```
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/css/owl.carousel.min.css</name></action>
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/owl.theme.default.css</name></action>
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/owl.carousel.min.js</name></action>
```

Add Carousal function in your custom js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:0,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:1
        },
        1000:{
            items:1
        }
    }
});
});
```

And your html should be

```
<div class="owl-carousel" id="owl-carousel">
   <div class="item"> Content 1</div>
   <div class="item"> Content 1</div>
   <div class="item"> Content 1</div>
</div>
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: working very well...

Comment: semicolon is optional if code after the supposed semicolon is in the new line and unless it is minified. Minification requires semicolon. You should ask the console error from the browser browser before saying that it is due to the semicolon.

Comment: i have edited my answer

Comment: i am currently using magento 1.9 is it ok to enqeue css and js file in local.xml

Comment: yes....u should use local.xml only to enqueue css and js file

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me in slider when I used owl carousel. I use a setTimeout function to load the code after some interval. Like this I had used in my file:

```
    setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery(".products-related .owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
            loop:true,
            margin:10,
            responsiveClass:true,
            responsive:{
                0:{
                    items:2,
                    nav:false,
                    loop: false
                },
                600:{
                    items:2,
                    nav:true
                },
                1000:{
                    items:3,
                    nav:true,
                    loop:false,
                    dots: false
                }
            }
        });
    }, 12000);
```